# ios - Regarding compatibility issue

Tags: ios, compatibility

I am making an iphone application. The target version is 6.0..
Recently I ran this app on ios 7.0 beta simulator and my app's user interface doesn't look good because of compatibility issue. MY question is, if I fix my app and change the target os to 7.0, will it still appear nicely on 6.0 or lower devices? 
Currently my app looks beautiful on 6.0. But I am worried that if I target 7.0, it might not look nice on 6.0 anymore.. What should I do? Is there a way for an app to target two different os versions with one build? Since App Store doesn't allow me to upload separate builds for the same app, I am a bit worried about this..

Comment: What doesn't look good? Are your relative placements not working anymore?

Comment: The only way to be sure is to give it a shot. i if you specifically target iOS 7.0 by changing the target OS you will not be able to run your app on 6.0. I would suggest waiting till September when iOS 7.0 is out of beta, i am sure all the hiccups and backward compatibility issues will be fixed by then and your app will look great on it.

Comment: I have tried running my app on iOS7 and found that the default alertview and actionsheet layout get changed. Is it your are worry about or there is something else?